# AWS Lambda next.js - Failed to post 2MB file to api route

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js, serverless

I deployed my `next.js` app to `aws` using`serverless-next.js` package.
When I'm trying to post a big file (~1MB) to the `api` route, I'm getting a `503` response code.
The full response content:

```
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>503 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: X
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

The CloudWatch log shows:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed",
    "code": "ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED",
    "stack": [
        "Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed",
        "    at WriteStream._write (internal/fs/streams.js:379:33)",
        "    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (internal/fs/streams.js:375:12)",
        "    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)",
        "    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:327:22)",
        "    at WriteStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)",
        "    at internal/fs/streams.js:366:10",
        "    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:156:23)"
    ]
}
```

I'm using formidable to parse the body of the request. It working with smaller file sizes.

What can I do? `1MB` does not count as big file size.

In development everything works even with 10MB files, but not in AWS lambda@edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's written here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

You can't have a request + response larger than 256 KB if you upload in  asynchronous mode.

Because serverless is only here to make your routes in lambda functions. If you want to upload this file, you can use S3 bucket with pre-signed url.
With that you doesn't need to upload the file to the lambda function.

Comment: The purpose is uploading images. The flow is that the client sends the file to my api route and the api route use aws sdk to upload to S3. in development everything works even with 10MB files, but not in aws lambda@edge.

Comment: That workflow isn't good in serverless. You need to interact the less with data in cloud. Check that tutorial https://www.serverless.com/blog/s3-one-time-signed-url

Comment: Ok thanks I will read it ! but why the error in cloudwatch logs is "ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED"?

Comment: I edited my answer, i hope that answer to your problem

Comment: "You can't have a request + response larger than 256 KB if you upload in asynchronous mode", 

but I am successfully uploading files with size 900KB. And what do you mean by "asynchronous mode"?